# JQuery Remove Table Row After Ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm aware that there are other questions similar to this one, however the way I've executed my code is much different and so it's complicated in how I'm supposed to implement the code into the script.
After executing an Ajax function when I click a button to delete a row, I want that row to fade out however each time I add to code to fade out there's always an error in the console.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<tr class="shift_type1">
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Time One</td>
    <td>Time Two</td>
    <td class="controlbuttons">
        <div class="settings">
            <span class="icons"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nnzONel.png" alt="X" /></span>
            <span class="icons" onclick="deleteRow('rowcodehereinphp')">Delete</span>
            <div class="icons">Edit</div>
            <div class="icons">Fill</div>
        </div> 
    </td>
    </tr>
```

**Here is the jQuery I use to delete the entry from my SQL database**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function fadeTr(code) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, 
        function(){ 
            // alert($(this).text());
        $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();                    
    });    
}
function deleteRow(code) {
        var proceed = true;
        if (proceed) {
            post_data = {'code': code};
            $.post('DeletePush.php', post_data, function (response) {
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
                } else {
                    output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                }
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }
                else {
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown().fadeTr(code);

                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    };
```

**Console Log Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
(anonymous function) 
j 
k.fireWith 
x 
b
```

Comment: Post console log error also. Or make a fiddle

Comment: @Manwal Error log posted, fiddle is useless because it won't execute without access to the php script

Answer (score 0):

Do this in a little different and easier way :

Suppose your html markup is like this below.
Just add the code to the class or the row. For example

```
<tr class="shift_type1_<?php echo $rowcodehereinphp; ?>">
.
.
.
</tr>
```

After this in your jquery or javascript

```
$(".shift_type1_"+code).fadeOut(slow);
Here "code" is the parameter which you will receive in your deleteRow(code) function.
```

Hope that helps.. Cheers..

Comment: This would execute the function regardless of whether or not the ajax function was executed

Comment: That is the point where you have to use your logic. I gave the answer with a code which will definitely work but how to use it that depends on you.

Comment: Your answer provides no assistance whatsoever it is essentially redundant, I could have easily mocked up a script that did this myself. Thanks for trying to go the easy way but it's not going to slide.

Comment: $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown().live(fadeTr(code));

and inside your fadeTr function you could have used my code. Anyways hope you will find your answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the selector of the row to be deleted and remove live function in fadeTr function. You can do something like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function deleteRow(code) {
        var proceed = true;
        if (proceed) {
            post_data = {'code': code};
            $.post('DeletePush.php', post_data, function (response) {
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
                } else {
                    output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';
                }
                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }
                else {
                    $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown().live(fadeTr(this));
                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    };
</script> 
<script>
function fadeTr(row) {
    $(row).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, 
        function(){ 
            // alert($(this).text());
        $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();                    
        });    
}
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Console log states that 'undefined is not a function'